# RegexExtract Syntax - Extract text after decimal/number from string ex. "UNDER 12.5-120"

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to write a RegexExtract formula to extract the odds of a bet.
My example text is `UNDER 12.5-120`.
In this example, I would hope to return `-120` but I need my equation to be dynamic enough to extract other odds as well.
More examples of this would be +120, +1200, +12000, -1000, etc etc.
The string will always be in this order though - `OVER` or `UNDER` then the line of the bet and then the odds of the bet. I have successfully written the regex for the line and the over/under but cant figure out the odds portion.

This is what I have so far:

`=REGEXEXTRACT('Form Responses 2'!C2,"[\d.,].*")` but this returns `12.5-120` and I need only the `-120`.

Comment: My thought was to identify the first decimal or number and extract everything after that decimal or number. Am I thinking of this correctly in terms of regex?

Comment: `[+-][\d]+` could work

Comment: This will work for all odds that start with a - but not a plus. I was able to use an OR operator to look for - or +. Thanks for the suggestion it works perfectly!

Comment: OR operator looses its special meaning in a character class expression so `[+-]` should work. `[+][\d]+|[-][\d]+` would be an option too. Note: dash must be at the beginning or end of the characters but that could change with the regex engine impl. Always at the end.

Comment: I need to use regex more often - so powerful. thanks LMC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for a range

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(Q2:Q8,"[-|+]\d+")))
```

If you want to have pure numbers try

=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(Q2:Q8,"[-|+]\d+")+0))

[image]

Comment: Thank you - what is the purpose of using Index and IfError in this equation? I am using =REGEXEXTRACT('Form Responses 2'!C2,"[-|+][\d]+") and it works but i wonder if I'm missing something

Comment: @mfajer Using `INDEX` you use a single formula for a whole range of ells. Using `IFERROR` you avoid error messages on let's say empty cells. Just try it.

Comment: Great idea! What's the +0 for at the end?

Comment: If you do **not** use the results will be a text string. But the `+` or `-` signs will be preserved. If on the other hand use `+0` the results will be numbers which could be used elsewhere. It depends on what you want to do with the results. Once more. Try it out :)

Comment: If I had enough rep I would upvote it - marked it as the answer as well. Appreciate it Marikamitsos

Comment: @mfajer *"If I had enough rep..."*.  There you go :)

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me!!!

```
=REGEXEXTRACT('Form Responses 2'!C2,"[-|+][\d]+")
```